# python module attribute error - subpackage

Tags: python, module, package

I tried looking through stackoverflow but did not find a specifc explanation on how this works or what causes this error. Here is my setup

python 3.6

here is my package structure

main.py
package1
  - **init**.py (empty)
  - subpackage1
     - **init**.py (empty)
     - module1.py

in main.py
import package1.subpackage1.module1 as moduel1

gives me this error

AttributeError: module 'package1.subpackage1' has no attribute 'module1'

Help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you include the full traceback? Also, where is this `a9apicalls` being called in the code?

Comment: If I reproduce the structure you gave, and execute that import, I don't get any error at all. I definitely don't get an error about a module named 'ocrapi.a9'. Is it possible that your `module1.py` file does something like `import ocrapi` and then tries to do `ocrapi.a9.a9apicalls()`, or indirectly calls some code that does that? Because the error is clearly about some module named `ocrapi`, not `module1`.

Comment: sorry wrong traceback..edited the post. but I still get the error. Are you mac or windows or it doesnt matter?